# How ODBC connect to SQL Anywhere 12

Tags: odbc, sqlanywhere, sys, rtd

[image]

I'm using sqlAnywhere 5.0 to create ODBC with third parties software house
I'm running it on windows XP without any error / problem
but 8/4/2014 Microsoft announce to stop service for windows XP
then our company migrate all client PC to windows 7x64
Now the application always hang and closed itself

I would like you suggest what can I do, I'm trying to test under SQL Anywhere 12.0 but I cannot config ODBC to open application

I also attached a picture (ODBC from rtdsh50.exe)
Start command is "C:\Starlims8\SqlAny50\Win32\rtdsk50.exe -d -c4000"

Please advise, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the image, you are using the version 5 runtime engine.  This software is almost 20 years old... I am not surprised you are having trouble getting it to run on Windows 7.

It doesn't look like you are providing a database file on the startline in the ODBC configuration.  Are you providing this somewhere else?  What does your actual connect string look like in the application?

Version 12 will probably not work, since your application was written for version 5. However, to even have a chance, you have to rebuild the version 5 database in version 12 format and then replace the SQLA version 5 ODBC data source with a version 12 one with the same name.
Is this an application that you/your company wrote or is it a third party app. you purchased?  Is it a 16 or 32 bit application?

Also, I would suggest setting the application up to run in compatibility mode as well as running it as an administrator.